# Rendering Bitmap with threading

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I'm generating spectogram out of many pixels. Problem is that it takes 0.8 second to render it. I would like to achieve that with threading so It doesn't freeze my GUI.

I'm very clueless. I tried many approaches but I can't get it working.

I need only this method to work and it should be fine.

```
 volatile DrawingVisual dv = new DrawingVisual();
    volatile RenderTargetBitmap rtb;
    volatile DrawingContext dc;
    private async Task<Image> GetSpectogram(List<int[]> Lines)
    {               
            using (dc = dv.RenderOpen())
            {                  
                int y = -1;
                int x = -1;
               
                foreach (int[] list in Lines)
                {
                    x += 1;
                    for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
                    {
                        y += 1;
                        int value = list[i];
                        dc.DrawRectangle(GetRGBFromValue(value), null, new Rect(x, y, 1, 1));
                    }
                    y = -1;
                }
                dc.Close();
            }

       await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
          
           rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(TotalLines, TotalPixelsInLine, 0, 0, PixelFormats.Default);
           rtb.Render(dv);

           Image img = new Image();
           img.Source = rtb;
           img.Height = rtb.Height * 3;
           img.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
           img.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;

           return img;
       });

        return null;
    }
```

Can you please tell me what is the problem here, I would like to understand it?
It is throwing threading error at rtb.Render(dv);

Thank you very much :)

Comment: You may also consider to write directly into the BackBuffer of a WriteableBitmap, which could be done from a thread other than the UI thread. There is also a WriteableBitmapEx library with extended features.

Comment: Yes I edited code when I'm returning RenderTargetBitmap. But it always return null for some reason, even when it isnt null before return

Comment: You do not use the return value of the Task action. It would however not work anyway, because you can not use UI elements that were created outside the UI thread in that thread, like the Image element in the Task action. All elements of a visual tree must be created in the same thread.

Comment: So it is impossible to achieve with my approach with RenderTargetBitmap? rtb.Render() works fine in other thread. Creating rectangle lets say, doesn't work it throws error.

Comment: As another note, the GetSpectogram should not return a `Task<Image>` but a `Task<BitmapSource>`. Then call `return await Task.Run(() => ... rtb.Freeze(); return rtb; });`

Comment: Or drop the `async` keyword from the method declaration and `return Task.Run(() => ...);`

Comment: Thank you very much life saver. I spent too much time with it :D I think I got it working. I just need to adjust something. *edit it is working, thank you <3 and I learned something about it